# Converting string to array in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have the following string: `var myArr = '["abc1", "abc4", "abc2", "zxy12", "abc3"]';`

I want to convert it to actual array. So I tried this:

```
var tempArray = JSON.parse("[" + myArr + "]");
var array = [];
for(var i = 0; i < tempArray[0].length; i++) {
    array.push(tempArray[0][i]);
}
```

It seems to be working, but I was wondering, is there a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: Uhm... `var array = JSON.parse(myArr);`???

Comment: Niet is right - if you hadn't wrapped the string `myArr` in square brackets it would parse directly into an array all by itself

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Right! What was I thinking... Feeling dumb... Thanks, man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var myArr = '["abc1", "abc4", "abc2", "zxy12", "abc3"]';
var op = JSON.parse(myArr);
console.log(op);
```